# Ampscript: Load Salesforce Campaigns to subscription control page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am building a custom Subscription Control centre in Marketing Cloud using Ampscript.

We are using Salesforce as the Database of Record.

Salesforce Campaigns will be used to record both lists and subscriber information.

Due to the lack of debug in MC Development, we are building this up layer by layer.

First layer is to list all Salesforce Campaigns where 'Type = Email'

Here is my code:

```
         %%[
            var @Campaigns, @CampaignNames, @CampaignNameRow, @y

            SET @Campaigns = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Campaign", "Name", "Type", "=", "Email")

            SET @CampaignCount = RowCount(@Campaigns)

            FOR @y = 1 TO @CampaignCount DO
              Set @CampaignNameRow = Field(Row(@Campaigns,@y),"Name")
              Set @CampaignNames = Concat(@CampaignNames, @CampaignNameRow, '  ') 
            NEXT @y

         ]%%
```

I am getting a 500 server error, so I've got something wrong... any help to understand what is much appreciated!

Does anyone have any advice on the method to debug Ampscript code on CloudPages?

Lastly, my next layer of functionality would be to add a checkbox for each Campaign that's loaded from the above code. The layer after that would be to check or uncheck the checkbox depending on the current subscribers status on each list (i.e. their Salesforce Campaign Member status, either Subscribed = checked, Unsubscribed or not on a Campaign Member currently = unchecked). Last layer is to then save the updated status back to the Campaign Member Status in Salesforce.

If anyone is feeling especially generous please feel free to jump forward to the next layers and fast-track our development!

Kind Regards

Matt

Comment: Update: this code is now working! I believe the 500 server error was a delay from publishing the code